# Stacked column graph in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

I would like to know (if it is possible) how to draw a plot like this in **R**.

[image: Example plot]

*E.g  30 persons (x-axis), work for almost 300-400 hours (y-axis), and each one allocated time in 6 specific activities showed in color*.

Example Data:

```
| People | Act 1 | Act 2 | Act 3 | Act 4 | Act 5 | Act 6 |
|Person 1|   18  |   20  |   32  |   75  |   64  |   18  |
|Person 1|   40  |   25  |   02  |   04  |   17  |   20  |
|Person 2|   58  |   45  |   32  |   75  |   64  |   18  |
|Person 3|   10  |   15  |   11  |   28  |   15  |   92  |
|Person 1|   11  |   11  |   02  |   05  |   04  |   08  |
```

I'm using this code:

```
plot(table(data$worker),col=unique(data$worker))
```

(this code gives me a different color to each bar)

but I can't find a way to color each bar based on the criteria I mentioned above.

Comment: The funny thing is that the example plot was clearly made in R...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a stacked column graph which shows the absolute value (total) of hours worked per person in the y axis, per type of activity.

First, organize your dataset like this:

```
person hours.worked activity
1      18           1
1      20           2
...
3      11           3
3      28           4
...
1      4            5
1      8            6
```

Then, do the following:

```
#reproducible example (same as OP's data)
df = structure(list(person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                    hours.worked = c(18L, 20L, 32L, 75L, 64L,18L, 40L, 25L, 2L, 4L, 17L, 20L, 58L, 45L, 32L, 75L, 64L, 18L, 10L, 15L, 11L, 28L, 15L, 92L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L),
                    activity = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)),
                   .Names = c("person", "hours.worked", "activity"), 
               class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -30L))

df$person = factor(df$person,levels=c(1,2,3)) #control person order in x axis (left to right)
df$activity = factor(df$activity,levels=c(6,5,4,3,2,1)) #control order of stacks within column (top to base)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=person,y=hours.worked,fill=activity)) +
  geom_col(position="stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), #control order of legend keys (top to bottom)
                    values = c("#F564E3","#619CFF","#00BFC4","#00BA38","#B79F00","#F8766D")) #control fill of legend keys and columns stacks (surprisingly, this will honor the order of factor levels instead of order of 'breaks')
```

[image]